# Planning folder structure for thousand files

Tags: vb.net, file, filesystems

The question: better a deep folder structure or less subfolder with thousands files?

The problem:
I have a VB.NET program that generates around 2500 XML files per year (circa 100 KB per file).
I have to store the files on a file server (Windows 7 or NAS).
On the network there are around 30 PCs using that program.

I am looking for the best way to plan the structure of the folders on the file server with the goal to have a good human-readable folders structure and at the same time a fast access to the file.

In the past I made a similar program with the following structure:

\fileserver\PC1\year\months\file00001.xml

in other words a folder for each PC on the LAN
then a subfolder for the years
then a subfolder for the months
and in the month-folder the files generated in the current month
(of course the filename has a special stamp)

in this way I got nearly 200 files per months.
This program run since years without problem.

But now I would like to remove the subfolder "MONTH" in order to have all the files generated by PC in the current year together in the subfolder year, as

\fileserver\PC1\year\file00001.xml

this solution would produce a clearer folder tree, but more files per folder.
I do not know if this could be an issue in term of speed by file accessing with vb.net programs or other third hand application.

Which folder structure would you choose?

Thanks for replying.

Comment: belongs on superuser/serverfault.

Comment: @tim: ok. I accepted the answer because it gave me the idea to make the test and then wanted to share my results with the community. I did not know how to proceed in the right way to do that.

Comment: @gingo No worries, it happens from time to time. You will be able to answer your own question shortly, if you'd like to do that I can re-open so you can move your solution to an actual answer that expands on the one you accepted.

Comment: @tim yes, I would like to move my solution, for the readibility of the issue would be the best thing, thanks.
Yesterday I could not post a new answer (due my reputations points)
It is not clear to me: shall I put my solution in a NEW answer or in the comment block of the answer I accepted? Is the comment block not too small fot the whole answer?

Comment: The comment block is way too small. I'd just say something like "Following up on [link]the answer I accpted[/link], I've implemented the following .. " , or similar. Let me know when you do it, and I'll remove this comment trail. The question has been re-opened.

Comment: ok, done! I hope I made it in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use NTFS, then measurements show that flat structure will work faster than dealing with subdirectories, but the difference is minimal (maybe 1% or even less, I don't have numbers at hand now).

Update: For one (single) file access less searches are involved and subdirectories offer better performance. But if you have random access to your files, then over time more and more files will be accessed and the OS will have to scan all directories and load them to memory. When it comes to processing large number of files, subdirectories tend to become slower. Also on NTFS, which has an index of file names, opening particular file is quite fast, and walking through subdirectories can be even slower, than opening the file from the same folder.

To summarize: speed significantly depends on usage scenario. I also believed, that grouping files into subdirectories would bring significant benefits, until I did tests. NTFS performed much better on hundreds of thousands of files in one folder, than one would expect. So I'd recommend making your own tests in your particular usage scenario.

Comment: This would mean that if I try to access to a file on a flat structure, that would be the faster way (ok, just 1%), even if I have to search in a folder with 2500 files istead of a small folder with only 200 files?

Comment: @gingo no, these numbers are for more or less random access to many files, when the file system has to scan many folders (or one large folder). It's not trivial to measure access speed for single file access.

Comment: Wait, I think for that statistic to be valid you have to assume that you're searching for a file without knowing the folder. If you know the folder, then a deeper tree is more efficient, because there are fewer entries to search at each level. But unless you're doing lots of searches or have truly huge numbers of files (thousands or more), the difference will be trivial.

Comment: @Jay I can confirm that a deeper tree is more efficient, at least in my test scenario (see the EDIT of my post).

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the [answer I accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336015/planning-folder-structure-for-thousand-files/7336502#7336502), I made some test in order to find an answer to my own question

I created a folder with 3000 files, it simulates the flat structure. Then I created a folder divided in 12 subfolders, each one with 250 files, they simulated the deep tree structure.

Then I wrote in vb6 a simple code to read 100 files from each folders and copy the binary data in an array. The file name was created randomly. I repeated 10 times the loop and calculated the average time.

Here the code for the flat folder.

```
dtTot = 0
For j = 1 To 10

   dtStart = GetTickCount

   For i = 1 To 100
     iFileNum = FreeFile
     iNr = Int(2999 * Rnd + 1)
     sFilename = sROOT & "2010\" & "raw (" & CStr(iNr) & ").dat"

     iNCount = (FileLen(sFilename) / 4
     ReDim lVetRawData(iNCount)

     Open sFilename For Binary Access Read As #iFileNum
     Get #iFileNum, , lVetRawData
     Close iFileNum

   Next i

 dtEnd = GetTickCount
 dtTot = dtTot + dtEnd - dtStart

Next j
```

I get the following result:

deep folder on NTFS 162,5 ms

flat folder on NTFS 196,9 ms

deep folder on NAS 280,2 ms

flat folder on NAS 340,7 ms

where the NTFS server is a Windows 2003 Pentium machine and the NAS is a Synology DS210j (linux based)

I repeated the test in different network conditions and got nearly similar value.

I hope I did not make any logical mistake and this is not an accurate measurament, but the test reproduces exactly the kind of access I have to do with my code: in all cases the deep folder structure seem to be faster one in my test environment.

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, then perhaps a database (full or simple file-based DB) is a better option?

Comment: yes, a ONLY-DB-Solution was in my mind too: my application already uses a DB (mdb access file) to store the location and more info about the files. In this way the user selects from the DB the file to see and I can retrieve from the DB the location of the file and the binary data.
Anyway I'd prefer to use also the file besides a DB, because:
1) I can store the data in a readable XML file, in this way third hand applications could easily access the info on the files.
2) the files contain binary data (> 100 KB) and I fear that the DB size could grow with the time (circa 7500 recors per day)

Comment: 1) You could argue that it is only one step harder, and that you can throw a simple tool in the folder with the DB that can query them 2) You can manage this out of DBs (archiving, dropping tables, partioning, etc).  It is arguably just as simple for a DBA, and you'd have more control.  For both points, though, it is probably easier for a dev who isn't super ultra comfortable with DBs to manage files.  I know this is true for me :)  But if perf becomes a driving concern, ease of access might get de-prioritized.